# Custom Filter Attribute or call in Action Method - Earlier in Request Pipeline but Performance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, action

I have a HomeController with about 8 or 9 Action Methods.

About 7 of these methods require a check to see if the User has a special setting or not to see if they are allowed to access these Methods and related Views.

If they are not they are redirected back to a Common Action Method and View.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() {
       UserManager um = new UserManager();
       um.Punter p = um.GetPunter(User.Identity.Name);
       return View(p);
    }
    public ActionResult PunterList() {
       UserManager um = new UserManager();
       um.Punter p = um.GetPunter(User.Identity.Name);
       if (p.isPunter) {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
       } else {
           return View(p);
       }
    }
}
```

The check in 'PunterList' is done in other Action Methods, I was thinking about creating a FilterAttribute to do this check.  As per the following:

```
public class NoPunterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter {
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
       UserManager um = new UserManager();
       um.Punter p = um.GetPunter(User.Identity.Name);
       if (p.isPunter) {
           filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Index" } });
       }
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) { }
}
```

then put this attribute on the Action method this type of user cannot access.

```
[NoPunter]
    public ActionResult PunterList() {
       UserManager um = new UserManager();
       um.Punter p = um.GetPunter(User.Identity.Name);
       return View(p);
    }
```

this puts this code in `1` place, However the `UserManager.GetPunter` is called twice if the `User.isPunter=false`.  Perhaps this is not such a good idea for Performance or Memory conservation of the MVC web application.

The benefit is does the check earlier in the Request pipeline, but perhaps a method called inside of the action method would mean .GetPunter would be called only once, but further along the Request pipeline.  Not sure about this, kind of split on earlier vs Performance/Memory issues.

Any suggestions or ideas would be interesting to hear.  Presumably it would depend on what is done inside `UserManager.GetPunter`.  There is some caching inside this call but it does requery the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom authorization attribute which will inject the Punter as a parameter of your action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        UserManager um = new UserManager();
        um.Punter p = um.GetPunter(User.Identity.Name);
        return View(p);
    }

    [NoPunterAuthorize]
    public ActionResult PunterList(Punter punter) 
    {
       return View(punter);
    }
}
```

and the custom authorization attribute:

```
public class NoPunterAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var um = new UserManager();
        var p = um.GetPunter(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        var routeData = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        routeData.Values["punter"] = p;
        return !p.IsPunter;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary 
            { 
                { "controller", "Home" }, 
                { "action", "Index" } 
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well an Unauthorized Request should be show a page which says they are not allowed.  A Punter can still login and use 2 of the Action Methods, while an Admin can use all, so I would not want to override HandleUnauthorizedRequest.  Still the question is more about performance of loading the Custom User object twice versus catching this earlier in the request pipeline.  I know AuthorizeAttribute occurs before FilterAttribute.

Comment: @magister, where in my example did you see the punter object being loaded twice? Did you notice how the custom authorize attribute is adding the result to the RouteData? Did you notice the signature of the `PunterList` controller action? As far as the Punter and Admin roles are concerned, you could simply tweak the attribute implementation so that it reads from the Roles property of the attribute.

Comment: ah ok no I missed the fact that you are putting the var p = um.GetPunter into a routeData.Values["punter"] = p;                      So you mean I can store my object in there and then still use it in the Action Method without having to call the method again?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I meant.

Comment: Passing the Punter into the RouteValues collection in the AuthorizeAttribute works, but when using a FilterAttribute to load it the ActionMethod loads with a null Punter.  Shame.  Probably better to deal with this in the AuthorizeAttribute but have to wait for another to implement some security and using a FilterAttribute was a temporary fix until the Identity Manager is implemented.